# android studio webbrowser get link when open as default webbrowser app

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I want to create a web browser and I succeed to defined it as the default one with those lines.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />


            </intent-filter>
```

but now when I, for example, go on Gmail and click on a link it opens my app but the problem is that I didn't find a way to make it capable of opening the app and make the Webview loading the link that I clicked in this example on Gmail. So how can I do so when another app launches the web browser, the javascript code is capable of getting the URL so that I can load it on the Webview with the command `mywebview.load(urlgetwhentheappopen);`?

***the code***

```
 try {
            String url = getIntent().getData().getPath();
            Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("link", url);
            WebView myweb=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
            myweb.loadUrl(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("error","no link"+String.valueOf(e));

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android OS passes the URL path to your app inside of `Intent` object.

in your WebBrowser activity you could get the link like this:

### Koltin

```
val url = intent.data?.toString()
```

### Java

```
String url = getIntent().getData().toString()
```

Then you can simply call:

```
mywebview.load ( url );
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, can it be possible that you help me with the intent.

Comment: When i do ` Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            String url = intent.getData().getPath();` I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null`

Comment: Oh sorry I edited my answer. You shouldn’t create a new intent, use the intent provided by the activity by using getIntent()

Comment: thanks, to continue to help but is it normal that it is equal to /r/ I put the code on the question body. because if yes the web view shows nothing. The link that I have chosen work with the android navigator

Comment: Try grtIntent().getData().toString()